# Writing to a NAS from a Raspberry Pi 2B - SMB or NFS?

Tags: performance, nfs

I'm familiar with Windows but a Linux newbie.  I have a Synology NAS which I want to use with my Raspberry Pi 2B (which is running Tvheadend).  The NAS supports NFS, SMB and AFP.  I want to minimise the load on the Pi when writing files to the NAS.  Which will load the Pi the least: NFS or SMB (or AFP)?

I know I could set it up and perform experiments but I'm struggling.  I've assumed NFS is the way to go but getting the Pi to talk NFS is proving tricky and I want to know if it's worth the effort to prioritise learning this stuff now.

Comment: NFS is trivial and a couple of orders of magnitude easier to use on Linux systems.  This Ubuntu tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo works OK on RaspiOS.

Answer (score 2):

Part of your question may be soliciting an opinion: `"...if it's worth the effort..."` But there is one part that I feel can be answered factually: **Forget about AFP... cross it off the list - *even if you use Apple hardware!***

You will find some (@Dougie - your cue) who feel NFS has all the advantages. Personally, I have decided to stick with SMB (Samba)... not because I think it's great - only because its *familiar*, and all I've seen and heard about NFS hasn't *incentivized me* to clutter my life with *Yet Another Protocol*. In other words: Samba is in my *comfort zone*, NFS doesn't seem worth the effort.

Of course this is 100% opinion - but when you boil it down, it's often a tradeoff: ***Do I invest my time to gain some performance advantage?*** That's usually a subjective decision because... because it's *your* time.

[Your question has been asked before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7117/which-to-use-nfs-or-samba) - it's [discussed frequently](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=NFS+vs+Samba&ia=web) in fact. And there are some articles that offer [**objective and empirical data.**](https://blog.ja-ke.tech/2019/08/27/nas-performance-sshfs-nfs-smb.html) But keep in mind that many of the Q&A/discussions you'll find online are focused on the **server** - not the client. Based on your question, it seems your RPi will only use the client-side software.

I feel the answer to your question is that any performance advantages of NFS or Samba will depend upon your use case. And unless your RPi 2B is running near 100% capacity, these advantages are likely to be irrelevant. If NFS *excites* you enough to try it, then try it. If not, stick with what you know, and apply your time to more relevant matters.

Comment: I'm familiar enough with other stackexchange sites to know not to ask for opinions!  I was hoping for data.  As you point out, I'm acting as client.  All of the questions I was able to find were from the pov of server so, since I don't know what I don't know, possibly invalid.  I wasn't asking your opinion of whether it was worth my time, I was fleshing out the question because all too often, people don't provide the why in SE questions and you go off down a blind alley answering the wrong question but I can see how it was misinterpretable.  Back to the drawing board!

Comment: @serialhobbyist: I'm ambivalent to the whole **opinion** thing - which is to say I'm happy to answer an **opinion** question as long as it has some, uh... "substance" :)  I think even the "official rules" here recognize opinions are a necessary ingredient for many valid questions. I think your question is a good example of that. Unfortunately, there seem to be no benchmarks for the NFS client, and even if there were, they'd only be applicable in a very *general* sort of way. I tried to present a *logical* answer, but not necessarily a *quantitative* one.